# Manipulate memory occupation

Tags: java, memory

In my program i generate some identifier ramdomly to identifier some characters. example:

```
12555678 to identify 'a'
12 to identify 'g'
13456789900000076 to identify 'c'
...
```

In my algorithm i cannot know what is size of these identifies. So, i use `BigInteger` numbers. I want to reduce on memory, then when i generate an identifier  `12` i can win in memory if i can use another type (not BigInteger). So my qestion is, is it possible to use another type to manipulate memory and rent only the exact size of my Identifiers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`BigInteger` is as large as it needs to be to represent the number (plus some overhead)

If you can use `Long` instead it will be smaller (as it has less over head) Using types smaller than Long won't make much difference as the over head is the same.

If you can use 64-bit signed values, using a `long` is as much as 5x smaller than using a `Long` so if memory is important I would find a way to limiting yourself to 18 trillion trillion identifiers.

Comment: +1 for the last line making clear that one can *probably* find a way to create a `long` value corresponding to each `char`...

Comment: There are less than 180 K characters which means you can have 100 million million ids for every character.

Comment: If you need an id for 100,000 characters and each id is an average size of 200 bytes then it will use about 20 MB which is not that much these days.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the fields to be of type `Number`, which would allow `BigInteger`s as well as `Integer`s or even `Short`s.

Depending on what methods you intended to call on the values, you might need to specifically check for the `BigInteger` case, and downcast to handle it separately.  Everything else could be handled via `number.longValue()`.

Doing this means that your references have the *ability* to hold a `BigInteger` when required, but you can instead pass in a `Short` to save memory when the value allows.